# Migrating from Python 2.5 to 2.7 on app engine with minimal effort

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, migration

I have some "old" GAE Python 2.5 applications, with a lot of code. This year we have to (goolge says) migrate to Python 2.7. I never touched the software for the last two years. The apps run fine without any administration. 
Some applications still use the Master/Slave datastore, which will be migrated first.

This software uses webapp and Jinja and no other external libraries besides SDK 1.7.2 (2012).

The scenario:
Keep webapp / CGI (do not change the code) and only change this yaml:

```
application: example
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
```

To:

```
application: example
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
```

And testing the applications with the new Python 2.7.

Is this the minimal effort scenario for migrating 2.5 applications to 2.7?

Comment: Minimal effort scenario? Yes :)

Comment: Though you should really change how you do you app definition. Rading through the migration guide is really important.

Comment: Making use of WSGI / webapp2 / threading and all the other benefits, is not important for this scenario. Not a priority. My only concern is: minimal effort. But thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's the minimum you can do, but you should go through [Migrate to Python 2.7](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27) documentation and make sure that all the points there are covered.

Comment: I have the same issue I have a site - uses 2.5 has been running nearly 10 years OMG. But it has just been depreciated. I have white-listed it but need to get it back safely asap with as little work as possible. It only servers static assets and uses web route handler to dynamically create pages vie webapp template. Has no user, no db, no mcache - can I just change the python version to 27 add threadsafe:false and it will run OK?

Comment: @MartinWebb since you use very few features you should be mostly okay, however, the guide does indicate that webapp templates are deprecated. They may work, or you may need to migrate those use jinja2 templates. The best thing to do is try doing the app.yaml updates and then deploy to a new service within your application.  If you have further issues, I recommend starting a new Stackoverflow question.